# Segmentation fault after returning zero

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

We are being taught programming using C in this semester and in our first assignment we were asked to print the list of values of sin(x), cos(x) and tan(x) using manual and library implementations. So, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define START   0
#define STOP    360
#define STEP    10

#define PI      3.14159265358979323846  /*For conversion: degrees <-> radians */

double rad(double x);   /* Converts angle in degrees to radians */
double next_term(double angle, int term_index);

/* Function prototypes for manual implementation of sin(x), cos(x) and tan(x) */
double sin_series(double x);
double cos_series(double x);
double tan_series(double x);


int main() {

    /* Creating and printing the table title:
    ** ==================================================================== */

    char table_title[] = "   n | ";
    strcat(table_title, "sin series | sin library | ");
    strcat(table_title, "cos series | cos library | ");
    strcat(table_title, "tan series | tan library | ");

    printf("%s \n", table_title);

    /* ==================================================================== */



    /* Creating and printing the line between the title and the table:
    ** ==================================================================== */

    char* second_line = (char*)malloc((strlen(table_title) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(table_title) - 1; i++) {
        second_line[i] = '=';
    }

    second_line[strlen(table_title)] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", second_line);

    /* ==================================================================== */

    free(second_line);

    /* Creating each line of the table and printing it:
    ** ==================================================================== */

    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 10) {

        printf("%4i | ", angle);
        printf("%10.5f | %11.5f | ",sin_series(angle), sin(rad(angle)) );
        printf("%10.5f | %11.5f | ",cos_series(angle), cos(rad(angle)) );
        printf("%10.5f | %11.5f | ",tan_series(angle), tan(rad(angle)) );
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;   
}

double rad(double x) {
    return ((PI * x) / 180);
}

double next_series_term(double angle, int term_index) {
    double result = 1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < term_index; i++) {
        result *= angle;
        result /= (i + 1);
    }

    return result;
}

unsigned long long factorial(int x) {

    unsigned long long result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        result *= (i + 1);
    }

    return result;
}

double sin_series(double x) {

    double result = 0;

    if (x == 0 || x == 180 || x == 360) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        /* Calculating the next term to add to result to increase precision.*/

        double next_term = next_series_term(rad(x), 2*i + 1);
        next_term *= pow(-1,i);


        result += next_term; 
        }
    }


    return result;  
}

double cos_series(double x) {

    double result = 0;

    if (x == 90 || x == 270) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        /* Calculating the next term to add to result to increase precision.*/

        double next_term = next_series_term(rad(x), 2*i);
        next_term *= pow(-1,i);     

        result += next_term; 
        }

    }

    return result;  
}

double tan_series(double x) {
        return sin_series(x)/cos_series(x); //non-portable! searching for
                                            // better solution
}
```

But this code results in Segmentation fault  after returning 0 as I found after using gdb and has left me completely baffled. Being a novice in C and programming, this has completely baffled me. Please help.

Comment: *What* is returning zero? *Where* is the crash?

Comment: @joachim Sorry. The crash is after main returns 0 and the table has been printed.

Comment: Oh, and [in C you should not cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and `sizeof(char)` is always `1` as per the C specification.

Comment: The strcatting to 'char table_title[]' has me worried straight off.

Comment: I mean the program crashes after the program has executed as expected.   Sorry for my bad english bu hope that this helps.

Comment: @MartinJames is it bad practise to do so ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok trying that now.

Comment: Yes - see @JoachimPileborg answer.  You've blown the main() return address on the stack.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal use `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf()` function, it clears the stdout buffer, and helps in locating the exact `segfault` location.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? I thought that this could be question to any beginner in C  not much acquainted with the internal workings of the C strings and the String library functions.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal - first thing to understand - C does not have a string type, (no not my downvote).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration

```
char table_title[] = "   n | ";
```

That declares `table_title` to be an array of *eight* characters. When you append other strings to the end of the array, you will write out of bounds and have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Either specify a size big enough to hold all the data you need, or initialize it properly with the complete string.

Comment: That means I cannot concatenate strings the way I am intending to without using extra memory ? Anyhow using a large buffer for the tite solved the problem. But still asking.

Comment: @AbhirupMondal you are not using "extra memory". Yes, you won't be able to store dozens of characters in an array of 8 characters. Is that surprising or what?

Comment: @AbhirupMondal If you don't specify a size when creating the array, it will be the exact size of the string you initialize it to. The `strcat` function doesn't reallocate or otherwise extend the destination string in any way, it just finds the string terminator and starts appending there.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. That clears up the things. But I was asking whether there was any way in C which could perform the task. (Reallocating memory and extending the string beyond the size of it when it was initialised)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I was speaking of extra memory as I need to allocate a large enough size most of which may be left unused.  Not that I was expecting to store dozens of characters in a 8 char string. :)

Comment: @AbhirupMondal Yes, declare it as a pointer, allocate the memory dynamically with [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), and use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to reallocate. This brings with it other problems though, and the esiest solution is to just plainly initialize the array with the *complete* string to begin with, there's no need to append a static string to another static string like you do.

Answer (score 1):

`table_title` you assign a string so the `sizof(table_title)` will not be able to hold the whole string which you are passing so accessing array out of bound is undefined behavior and might cause crash.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you use table_title? There is no need. Just use printf.

```
printf ("sin series | sin library | cos series | cos library | tan series | tan library | ");
```

You declared table_title statically. free() is used to deallocate memory that you allocated dynamically. So do it. There wont be segmentation fault.

Comment: I need to print the code and submit it for grading. So your option results in line wraps which our instructor does not like. So I felt that to be the solution. Also I needed the string length for the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Ok then you can use printf as

```
printf (
    "sin series | sin library | " \
    "cos series | cos library | " \
    "tan series | tan library | ");
```

There is no wraps. Try this. :)